# Change colors of text based on while loop from an array of colors

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I want to run a forloop inside a while loop so that i will be able to change the colors of text accordingly. This is my code

```
       $leftBrdColorArray = array("g-brd-blue-left", "g-brd-red-left", "g-brd-black-left", "g-brd-yellow-left");
        $rowCount = $runselectGameInfo -> num_rows; //3 is the count
         if($runselectGameInfo -> num_rows > 0){
           while($getGameInfo = $runselectGameInfo -> fetch_assoc()){

             for($i = 0; $i <= $rowCount; $i++){

           Hello <div class="<?php echo $leftBrdColorArray[$i];?>">World</div>
         }
    }
}
```

But it prints 12 times insted of the rowcount i.e 3.

Comment: Sure! You are looping twice!! Your while and for loops are just the same.

Comment: probably the `while` loop runs twice. For each run the `for` loop runs 3 times. `$runselectGameInfo -> fetch_assoc()`  have 2 results in it. make an `echo` statement inside the `while` loop but outside the `for` loop to test how many times it runs

Comment: If possible can you illustrate with code. How do i achieve this?

Comment: `for` loop runs for the values of `$i` starting from 0 to 3 inclusive, that is 4 times. Are you sure you get the printing 6 times ?

Comment: @BRAHMANANDAMOHANTYBRAHMA, did you do the test I suggested ?

Comment: 12 times it is coming

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Actually i didn;t get what you suggested.

Comment: 12 times sounds right. Your `while` loop runs 3 times (3 rows) and prints 4 times in the for loop (0 to 3, inclusive).

Comment: @BRAHMANANDAMOHANTYBRAHMA,expected result is  12 times. You said ,"3 is the count". `while` loop also works 3 times for the  condition `$getGameInfo = $runselectGameInfo -> fetch_assoc()`. For each time the inner `for` loop runs 4 times. 3x4=12. That is what you get

Comment: Yes. But what i want is it should run same as while so that from array only 3 colors will be picked and changed, and in the same way if the count increases it should repeat the colors according to the order of array they are stored.

Comment: @BRAHMANANDAMOHANTYBRAHMA, why do you need the `for` loop ?

Comment: Then how can i get what i want, any other solution?

Comment: @BRAHMANANDAMOHANTYBRAHMA, can the value of `$rowCount` be more than the size of the array ` $leftBrdColorArray` i,e. 4 ?

Comment: @PauloHgo Suggested a solution and that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just print a different color every time but not necessarily all 4 of them (for each row), then the following should do it:

```
$leftBrdColorArray = array("g-brd-blue-left", "g-brd-red-left", "g-brd-black-left", "g-brd-yellow-left");
$arrsize = count($leftBrdColorArray);
        $rowCount = $runselectGameInfo -> num_rows; //3 is the count
         if($runselectGameInfo -> num_rows > 0){
           i=0;
           while($getGameInfo = $runselectGameInfo -> fetch_assoc()){
             if($i > $arrsize - 1) $i = 0;
             echo 'Hello <div class="$leftBrdColorArray[$i]">World</div>';
             i++;
         }
    }
```

The problem here will be if you have more rows than colors... you'd have to manage that and add logic to just get a color within the range of your array.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what i want to achieve, i am trying to get the logic, coz as per you once the loop has more rows than my colors it will be emptied. But i want that to run and colors to be repeated.

Comment: I just edited the answer. You have to know the size of the array of colors and the check if has reached the last one, bring it back to zero. I didn't test but this should work.

Comment: YES THIS ONE IS WORKING.